# Show div on hover of list item and keep it visible until new hover on another list element

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm looking for a solution to keep a div visible on hover and it should stay visible until I'm hovering again and not on a mouseout event.

Current markup of the list which can be hovered:

```
<ul class="crops-archive-home">           
    <li class="vegetables" style="background: #85bc22">        
        <a href="#">Vegetables</a>      
    </li>         
    <li class="bedding-plants" style="background: #00843a">        
        <a href="#">Bedding plants</a>      
    </li>
  etc....
</ul>
```

And the divs that need to be shown on hover

```
<div class="quote vegetables" style="background: rgba(133,188,34,0.8)">        

    <p>Lorem ipsum advised growbags and growblocks</p>                  
    <hr>
    <p class="sub-quote">Now Victor can grow peat-free and organic</p>

</div>

<div class="quote bedding-plants" style="background: rgba(0,132,58,0.8)">          

    <p>Bedding plants root best on Lorem Ipsum Substrates</p>
    <hr>
    <p class="sub-quote">Healthy plants, stronger roots</p>

</div> 

etc....
```

This is the current CSS

```
.quote{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s 5s;
}   

.quote.active{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .4s;
}
```

And the jQuery used:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".vegetables").hover(function(){
        jQuery('.quote.vegetables').toggleClass('active');   
    }); 
    jQuery(".bedding-plants").hover(function(){
        jQuery('.quote.bedding-plants').toggleClass('active');   
    });
etc.... 
};
```

Current setup shows the quote div on hover, it remains visible for 5 seconds but can overlap with another quote when hovered over a new link within 5 seconds.

Already tried it with .`show()` and `.hide()` but then the quote disappears instantly.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a specific group of divs that are part of this logic, instead of toggling the class, you would be better off adding (instead of toggling) the `active` class on hover and at the same time, removing the `active` class from the other elements that are part of that logic by looping through an array of those elements.

You could also keep track of the active class in a variable and update that on each hover instead of looping through an array of the other elements.

The key is to use `.addClass` instead of `toggleClass`.

To remove the existing `active` classes:

```
$('div.quote').each(function(div) {
     div.removeClass('active');
})
```

Comment: That seems to be the right way with using `.addClass.` Now I only need to find a way to remove the active class form the other elements like you suggested. I'm a real jQuery novice but I guess it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I updated my answer for that. That would be added to the hover function to before adding the ```active``` class to the new hovered element.

Comment: Thanks, I'm only getting an error though when adding your code: TypeError: div.removeClass is not a function

Comment: how about ```this.removeClass('active')```?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply due to the weekend in between but I solved it with adding `jQuery('.quote').removeClass('active');` right before `jQuery('.quote.bedding-plants').toggleClass('active');` Thanks again for pointing me intro the right direction!